# MongoDB- could not find member to sync from

Tags: mongodb

Node logs under Recovery mode, even after restarting:

```
    2018-04-24T12:37:52.915+0530 I REPL [replication-0] We are too stale to use J-DB-02:27017 as a sync source. Blacklisting this sync source because our last fetched timestamp: 5ade01e0:66 is before their earliest timestamp: 5aded094:198 for 1min until: 2018-04-24T12:38:52.915+0530 2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 I REPL [replication-0] could not find member to sync from 2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 E REPL [rsBackgroundSync] too stale to catch up -- entering maintenance mode 2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 I REPL [rsBackgroundSync] Our newest OpTime : { ts: Timestamp 1524498912000|102, t: 68 } 2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 I REPL [rsBackgroundSync] Earliest OpTime available is { ts: Timestamp 1524551828000|408, t: 68 } 2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 I REPL [rsBackgroundSync] See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/resyncingaverystalereplicasetmember 2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 I REPL [rsBackgroundSync] going into maintenance mode with 0 other maintenance mode tasks in progress 2018-04-24T12:37:52.916+0530 I REPL [rsBackgroundSync] transition to RECOVERING
```

Here is the status of replica set from primary server

```
    WAPRS01:PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.stats().maxSize
    WAPRS01:PRIMARY> rs.status();
    {
            "set" : "WAPRS01",
            "date" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:15.276Z"),
            "myState" : 1,
            "term" : NumberLong(68),
            "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
            "optimes" : {
                    "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1524498912, 102),
                            "t" : NumberLong(68)
                    },
                    "appliedOpTime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1524554235, 160),
                            "t" : NumberLong(68)
                    },
                    "durableOpTime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1524554235, 92),
                            "t" : NumberLong(68)
                    }
            },
            "members" : [
                    {
                            "_id" : 0,
                            "name" : "J-DB-01:27017",
                            "health" : 1,
                            "state" : 3,
                            "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
                            "uptime" : 569,
                            "optime" : {
                                    "ts" : Timestamp(1524498912, 102),
                                    "t" : NumberLong(68)
                            },
                            "optimeDurable" : {
                                    "ts" : Timestamp(1524498912, 102),
                                    "t" : NumberLong(68)
                            },
                            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-04-23T15:55:12Z"),
                            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2018-04-23T15:55:12Z"),
                            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:13.532Z"),
                            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:13.493Z"),
                            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                            "configVersion" : 4
                    },
                    {
                            "_id" : 1,
                            "name" : "J-DB-02:27017",
                            "health" : 1,
                            "state" : 2,
                            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                            "uptime" : 299382,
                            "optime" : {
                                    "ts" : Timestamp(1524554232, 270),
                                    "t" : NumberLong(68)
                            },
                            "optimeDurable" : {
                                    "ts" : Timestamp(1524554232, 270),
                                    "t" : NumberLong(68)
                            },
                            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:12Z"),
                            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:12Z"),
                            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:13.454Z"),
                            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:13.864Z"),
                            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                            "syncingTo" : "J-DB-03:27017",
                            "configVersion" : 4
                    },
                    {
                            "_id" : 2,
                            "name" : "J-DB-03:27017",
                            "health" : 1,
                            "state" : 1,
                            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                            "uptime" : 613420,
                            "optime" : {
                                    "ts" : Timestamp(1524554235, 160),
                                    "t" : NumberLong(68)
                            },
                            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:15Z"),
                            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1524254862, 1),
                            "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-04-20T20:07:42Z"),
                            "configVersion" : 4,
                            "self" : true
                    },
                    {
                            "_id" : 3,
                            "name" : "J-DB-04:27017",
                            "health" : 1,
                            "state" : 7,
                            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                            "uptime" : 300361,
                            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:14.863Z"),
                            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-04-24T07:17:14.229Z"),
                            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                            "configVersion" : 4
                    }
            ],`enter code here`
            "ok" : 1
    }
    WAPRS01:PRIMARY>
```

db.isMaster():

```
WAPRS01:PRIMARY> db.isMaster();
{
        "hosts" : [
                "J-DB-01:27017",
                "J-DB-02:27017",
                "J-DB-03:27017"
        ],
        "arbiters" : [
                "J-DB-04:27017"
        ],
        "setName" : "WAPRS01",
        "setVersion" : 4,
        "ismaster" : true,
        "secondary" : false,
        "primary" : "J-DB-03:27017",
        "me" : "J-DB-03:27017",
        "electionId" : ObjectId("7fffffff0000000000000044"),
        "lastWrite" : {
                "opTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1524559624, 465),
                        "t" : NumberLong(68)
                },
                "lastWriteDate" : ISODate("2018-04-24T08:47:04Z")
        },
        "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
        "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
        "maxWriteBatchSize" : 1000,
        "localTime" : ISODate("2018-04-24T08:47:04.511Z"),
        "maxWireVersion" : 5,
        "minWireVersion" : 0,
        "readOnly" : false,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: ,Are you sure . Is it Primary Replica Set reports status. Did you checked through "db.isMaster()".Through which you can confirm your Primary Replica as well as Secondary replica.

Comment: have added db.isMaster() results also above

Comment: @ RishiTyagi,Yes, As per db.isMaster() reports  "ismaster" : true. That Replica Set Server is Primary.

Comment: you are right, I had added above status of primary server and error logs from the replica server which is causing issues

Comment: ,As from your rs.status() reports, i am able to see your one of secondary replica node is showing in "Recovering" state.please post mongodb.log from RECOVERING nodes.

Answer (score 5):

As I am able to see from your `rs.status()` , there is secondary replica is showing in **`RECOVERING`** state. And as MongoDB jira blog [After node goes into RECOVERING due to being too stale to sync from its source, it will never recover even if there is a valid sync source it could use](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-26360).

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/) A [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-replica-set) member becomes “stale” when its replication process falls so far behind that the [primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-primary) overwrites oplog entries the member has not yet replicated. The member cannot catch up and becomes “stale.” When this occurs, you must completely resynchronize the member by removing its data and performing an [initial sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#replica-set-initial-sync).

For further your ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/) , [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154464/mongodb-replication-going-into-maintenance-mode-with-10333-other-maintenance-mo) , [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-26360), [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27815) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/PEeTIWC190k/HOQqO4kcAwAJ)

Comment: This is the state again after reading 75% data post resynch is started by clearing all data on the server, Initially it was showing StartUP-2 state and then went into RECOVERING State again

Answer (score 0):

The member is in `RECOVERING` since its performing startup self-checks & it is not able to transient into the `SECONDARY` state since it contains stale data which is due to the **oplog size** issue.

You could change the size of the oplog using the below steps:

**Increasing oplog:**

Shutdown the primary server

```
use admin

db.shutdownServer()
```

Start primary as standalone & run on different port say 37017

Login to mongo in port 37017

```
mongo --port 37017
```

Remove the old contents in local database

For safety have backop of old oplog before dropping

```
mongodump --db local --collection 'oplog.rs' --port 37017
```

Drop the old contents in local database

```
use local

db.oplog.rs.drop()

db.me.drop()

db.replset.election.drop()

db.replset.minvalid.drop()

db.startup_log.drop()
```

Replset collection cannot be dropped so remove it with required id :

```
db.system.replset.remove({ "_id" : "your_replsetname"})
```

Create a new oplog of required size say 50 GB

```
db.runCommand( { create: "oplog.rs", capped: true, size: (50 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) } )
```

Also you can specify the oplog size in MB in mongod.conf file,say for 50 GB its 429496 MB

```
replication:
   oplogSizeMB: 429496
```

Hope this Helps !!!

Comment: 429496 MB = 429496000000 Byte = 400 GiByte (not 50 GiByte)

Comment: could we increase oplog size with replSetResizeOplog in rs instead of stopping database? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetResizeOplog/

Comment: @Melih Yes ,you can increase oplog size `online` now